# How to add an ui input box when calling an external script in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code in a Google App Script.

```
    function FixColumns(r) {//I thought you would want to make r an argument like this
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
    var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
    for (var s in allsheets){
      var sheet=allsheets[s];
      if(s > r) {
      var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns(); 
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      if (maxColumns-lastColumn != 0){
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 145);
        sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn+1, maxColumns-lastColumn);
          }
        }
      }
    }

function doGet(e) {
      return FixColumns();
    }
```

And on my spreadsheet I fetch the script to run it only server-side.

```
function FixColumnsEx() {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL");
    }
```

But I want to be able to define the "r" variable, preferably with an UI input box that appears when I run the script in the spreadsheet. I have tried to mess with UiApp but I'm just completing stumped.
I know how to do it client-side.

```
var response = ui.prompt('Start on sheet:');
var r = response.getResponseText();
var r = +r;
```

But this throws a context error when I put it in the FixColumns function above since it's server-sided.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the whole thing.

fixcolumn.gs:

```
function onOpen()//Run this once from the script editor to create a menu
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('Show Dialog', 'showDialog')
}
function FixColumns(r) 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets){
    var sheet=allsheets[s];
    if(s > r) {
      var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns(); 
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      if (maxColumns-lastColumn != 0){
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 145);
        sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn+1, maxColumns-lastColumn);
      }
    }
  }
}
//Run this function to get everything going.
function showDialog() {
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('fixcolumn')
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Fix Columns')
}
```

fixcolumn.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     function fixAColumn()
     {
         var r=$('#txt').val();
         if(r)
         {
           google.script.run.FixColumns(r);
         }
      }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Column Number:<input type="text" id="txt" /></label>
    <input type="button" value="Fix Column" onClick="fixAColumn();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what it looks like when it runs:

[image]

Here's the version I used just to debug my stuff.  I didn't debug any of your code. I just wanted to make sure I could get a round trip to the gs code and back to make sure everything was working okay.

```
function NotonOpen()//Run this once from the script editor create a menu
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('Show Dialog', 'showDialog')
}

function FixColumns(r) 
{
  return true;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets){
    var sheet=allsheets[s];
    if(s > r) {
      var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns(); 
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      if (maxColumns-lastColumn != 0){
        sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 145);
        sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn+1, maxColumns-lastColumn);
      }
    }
  }

}

function showDialog() {
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('fixcolumn')
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Fix Columns')
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     function fixAColumn()
     {
       $('#txt').css('background-color','#ffff00');
         var r=$('#txt').val();
         if(r)
         {
           google.script.run
             .withSuccessHandler(clrYellow)
             .FixColumns(r);
         }
      }
      function clrYellow()
      {
        $('#txt').css('background-color','#ffffff');
      }
      console.log('My code');
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Column Number:<input type="text" id="txt" /></label>
    <input type="button" value="Fix Column" onClick="fixAColumn();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

You could also do this with a SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt().  But this is a good thing to learn and get comfortable with because you can use this later if you want to make a webapp.

Comment: Sorry, but how am I meant to use showDialog exactly? I have tried so things but not entirely sure as nothing happens when I run the script in the spreadsheet.

Comment: You run the dialog.  Enter your r value into the text box and click on Fix Column button,  It goes to the javascript function fixAColumn which collects the r value from the textbox and calls the fixColumns(r) function.  I assumed you could make r a parameter of fixColumns().  It doesn't return anything so there is no withSuccessHandler.  I just edited your question to reflect what I was suggesting.  I'll be happy to change it back if that's not okay with you.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I meant where/how should I run it. 
It obviously gives an error if I run it from the GAS project itself and if I include it in doGet nothing happens.

Comment: I also tried to add the html file to the spreadsheet itself along with the showDialog function and added showDialog to the function that fetches from the external script and then the ui showed up but the scripts finishes running before I can input anything (seems like it's not waiting for the input).

Comment: I had a few errors in there.  I think I got them all now.